# evil mode j and k moves between paragraphs instead of lines on markdown and text modes

Tags: evil

evil mode j and k in markdown and text modes moves down paragraphs (and sometimes to other arbitrary points down/up the paragraph) instead of up and down a single line. How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: What does `F1 k j` say? I have a hard time believing this is Evil's fault.

Comment: Here's what it says: `j runs the command evil-next-line (found in evil-motion-state-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `evil-commands.el'.                                                                  
It is bound to <down>, j.                                                                                                              
(evil-next-line &optional COUNT)                                                                                                       
Move the cursor COUNT lines down.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely happening because you have visual-line mode enabled and each paragraph is a single line. You can rebind j and k to move by visual line (evil-next-visual-line for j, for instance).

Comment: This worked thanks!